# How to convert an IIS folder to an application?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, iis

When I want to convert a folder to an application, I proceed as below screenshot.

I'm looking for script to do this from a batch-command/.bat-file. Is it possible?

If it is, please share. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ConvertTo-WebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807827.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet.  The graphic interface executes the same command.

Comment: @Paradroid How can we run a .bat file via PowerShell by double click it ?

Comment: @Nam: you can probably use a .bat file that runs the PowerShell command, but that seems silly. You can execute the PowerShell .ps1 script from the Run box or make a shortcut for it.

Comment: @Paradroid Calling `ConvertTo-WebApplication` failed on my PowerShell. Trying to call `add-pssnapin WebAdministration` also failed. What should I do now?

Comment: @Nam: Make sure you have the IIS admin tools installed and try `Import-Module WebAdministration`

Comment: @Nam: So did you sort it out in the end?

Comment: @Paradroid I'll let you know and pick up yours as selected answer when I tried. At the moment I'm looking at NAnt script, seems to be much simpler to me.